# How to reduce code redundancy while subclassing views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a requirement where I need to alter UIComponents like UIButton, UIView and UITextField. What I need to do is just to make change the radius of border to round rather than sharp rectangle which is default.

The way I have done this is to subclass **UIView to UIViewRoundCorner**, **UIButton to UIButtonRoundCorner**, **UITextField to UITextFieldRoundCorner** and inside each subclass I have overridden the drawRect Method with this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
}
```

The code is redundant and I am trying to figure out how to remove this redundancy. Since all these element is being inherited from UIView, is it possible somehow to subclass UIView and implement in all the other views?

Comment: FYI - Using `drawRect:` to tweak the layer is not the right thing to do. `drawRect:` can get called many times in the life time of the control but you only need to tweak the layer once. Do it in an appropriate `init...` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). I will implement right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protocol RoundedCorner {
    func makeCornerRadius(radius:CGFloat)
}

extension RoundedCorner where Self:UIView{
    func makeCornerRadius(radius:CGFloat){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton, RoundedCorner {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        self.makeCornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

you can create a protocol and extend that protocol for default implementation. and then for every custom view for which you want corner radius, just implement that protocol. This way you can minimise your code redundancy.

Comment: Why not extend UIview itself rather than extending a protocol??

Answer (score 2):

You don't need subclassing at all to do this. Objective-C has a wonderful feature, that allows you to add behavior to *existing* classes: [categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

You can add a method in a category on `UIView` (let's call it `RoundedCorners`):

```
@implementation UIView (RoundedCorners)

- (void)ps_addRoundedCorners;

@end

@implementation UIView (RoundedCorners)

- (void)ps_addRoundedCorners {
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0f]; 
}

@end
```

And use it with any `UIView` subclass:

```
UIButton *button = ...  //create a button somehow
[button ps_addRoundedCorners];
```

The `ps_` prefix in the method name is used to avoid name clashing (in case if someone else added a method with the same name in a private framework).